# Peewee : How to update specific fields?

Tags: database, python-2.7, orm, peewee

I'm using `Peewee` for working with database. I have a `User` tables with 3 fields: `username`, `password` and `last_login`. When a user login to the system i want to update `last_login`. I've use following lines of code:

```
from peewee import *
import datetime

class User(Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField()
    last_login = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        database = MySQLDatabase('mydb', user='root', charset='123456')


u=User(username="user1", last_login=datetime.datetime.now())
u.save()
```

Although i haven't specified any value for `password`, it is overwritten after `u.save()` is called. How should i force peewee to only update `last_login` field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `u.save()` with:

```
u.save(only=[User.last_login])
```

As the [API's documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.save) says:

> **only (list)** – A list of fields to persist – when supplied, only the  given fields will be persisted.

So you should specify a list of fields you want to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `only` argument when calling `save()`. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.save

> When a user login to the system i want to update last_login. I've use following lines of code:

If you want to do this, you should do an atomic update, however:

```
User.update({User.last_login: datetime.datetime.now()}).where(User.username == 'whatever').execute()
```

Comment: What's difference? Which one is better method?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will demonstrate how to create, get and update a record in the database:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# create a user
u = User.create(username="user1", password="bla", last_login=now)
# now `u` has your user, you can do: print u.username, u.password, u.last_login

# get an existing user from the db
u = User.get(User.username == "user1")
print u.username, u.password, u.last_login

sleep(1)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# update an existing user
u = User.update(password="blabla", last_login=now).where(User.username == "user1")
u.execute()
```

Comment: I don't want to change the password. your code changes it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save only modified fields, you may use the method below:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField()
    last_login = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        database = MySQLDatabase('mydb', user='root', charset='123456')

        # This method saves only modefied fields
        only_save_dirty = True

u=User(username="user1", last_login=datetime.datetime.now())
u.save()
```